# Communication between a python server and a C# client (Unity)

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, websocket

Below you can see both of the python server and the C# client scripts, the process is to send and receive packets.

I connect to the server via cloud, using Putty to connect to it, the client is an application created using Unity and C# script.

**server.py**:

```
import socket

port = 80
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = socket.gethostname()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

print("server listening...")

while True:
    client, adr = s.accept()
    print(f"got connection from ",adr)

    client.send(bytes("welcome from the server","utf-8"))
    data = client.recv(1024)

    print("server received", data.decode("utf-8"))
    client.close()
```

**client.cs**: I use here the WebSocketSharp library.

```
public class client: MonoBehaviour
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello I'm the client");

    void Start()
    {
        using (WebSocket ws = new WebSocket("ws://arb-server.tunis-plm.com/"))
        {
            ws.Connect();

            ws.Send(buffer);

            ws.OnMessage += Ws_OnMessage;

        }

    }       

    private void Ws_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.Data);
    }
}
```

The problem here that I can't receive data from server, the same thing for the client, I can't receive data from the client, also I don't know if my message sent or not, however, in the server console I received a connection from the client, thanks to this two lines of code in the server script:

```
client, adr = s.accept()
print(f"Got connection from ",adr)
```

So the result it's *Got connection from ('193.168.1.255',3112)*.

Here is the complete output from the server side:

[image]

And this is what I receive from the web browser:
[image]

I took an effort to solve this issue but no result yet, if someone can help me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your `using` block. It will `Dispose` the `ws` as soon as the `Start` method has finished (or actually as soon as the `using` block has reached the end).

I think you'd rather do something like

```
private WebSocket ws;

private void Start ()
{
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://arb-server.tunis-plm.com/"))

    // In general I would move this up
    // what if you already receive a message right when connected
    // but before your code had time to add the callback
    ws.OnMessage += Ws_OnMessage;
 
    ws.Connect();

    ws.Send(buffer);           
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    ws?.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: So you think that the problem came from the `using` ?

Comment: @Sekmani52 yes, I think you are disposing the socket before it has a chance to receive anything

Comment: I try your solution, but the same problem, let me show you the output of the server, i will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is no longer relevant, but nevertheless I will try to answer.
It's all about the HTTP protocol. As I see it, you are trying to connect to your server like a website, but for this you need to send a correct response so that the client can see it. You can read more details here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview#responses

In short, you need to send a response like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content Length: 11

Hello World
```

Or for python

```
client.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Length: 11\n\nHello World')
```

This applies to cases if you want to implement communication over the HTTP protocol, and your server would send a response in the form of HTML or JSON format.

I hope I could help you clarify this situation.